# Jetpack compose navigation architecture without fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am a bit confused about the new Jetpack compose navigation component androidx.navigation:navigation-compose documented at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation.

Am I right to say that the single-activity architecture with 0 fragment is preferred to the single-activity architecture with multiple fragments when using Jetpack Compose ?

I know we can still use fragments and Jetpack compose in this manner :

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply{
            setContent {
                MyFragmentComposable()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to make sure that when using androidx.navigation:navigation-compose, we are not supposed to use fragment anymore, starting like so:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you are correct. Using no fragments is preferred. You can use a `NavHost` to declare your navigation graph.

Comment: What about PreferenceFragmentCompat for settings? Do we have to code settings manually ? I did not see anything about settings in Jetpack Compose doc.

Comment: I don't know anything about preferences, but you should probably stick to fragments for now if you need interoperability with the old view system. You can check out the [Crane compose sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Crane) for using Android Views inside Compose

Comment: I see. To be honest, I don't see the need to keep lifecycle as it is any more with Jetpack compose. For example, the screen could just be recomposed entirely under configuration change instead of destroying the activity. That would be much simplier. But I may have missed something.

Comment: Is the answer just an opinion or relies on any information pointed out on Android developer website?

Comment: @rocknow the android documentation recommends using the compose navigation library (developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation). Using fragments in a compose-only app is unwieldy and adds excess boilerplate.